# search drop down name replace with parent category

Tags: magento-1.9, search, parent-child-theme

I am using ultimo magento theme.
In this Each search drop down has a text "ALL CATEGORIES".

Anyone can replace with parent category?

my folder path is

```
app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalogsearch/form/contents.phtml
```

Comment: You should contact Ultimo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimo is a paid extension we don't have access to so we can't help you but it sounds like it's using the default `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml`

on line 66 it has this piece of code

```
$html .= $this->__('View All') . ' ' . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
```

You would need to replace that with what ever you want to display there